# Bash - selecting random file pairs

Tags: bash

I have a folder containing thousands of images. These images come in pairs, where one will have a name like `apple_0_2_3_suffix1.png` and the other will have a name like `apple_0_2_3_suffix2.png`. I would like to write a Bash script that randomly selects 70% of these pairs and moves them into another folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Also -- do you need *exactly* 70%, or is it sufficient for each individual pair to have a 70% chance of being moved?

Comment: @ruakh: i actually haven't used bash scripting in a *very* long time and right i'm working on other stuff. Also, i need exactly 70%. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: What happens when there are 8 pairs of files? Exactly 70% of 8 is 5.6 pairs of files — do you mean 'up to 70%' or 'at least 70%' or have you got a way of creating fractional files?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: well, approximation is obviously needed. One file more or one less doens't change much for me.

Comment: So you don't need 'exactly 70%'.  Programming does, unfortunately, require precision in the specification...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I do this?

there is one idea:

1. list all `apple*suffix1.png`
2. save the output of above into a file, say `suffix1.list`
3. now you can know the 70% is how many files (or rows in that `suffix1.list`), let say, `n` lines
4. `shuf`  the file, just take first `n` lines. (shuf command could be used)
5. here you could use awk,sed to generate `mv` commands for you, or use a `for loop` to move file to dest dir. important is, when you print one "mv " command or move one file, you need to print/move the corresponding file with the other suffix2.

**note**

that you could avoid to store the file `suffix1.list` if you write one script. I just used the file since it could somehow simplify the process. Also it is easier to explain my idea.

let me know if "***ideas won't help me, I just want the running codes.***"

**EDIT** op wants codes:

**1) simulate your `suf1` file list:**

```
kent$  seq -f "apple_%03g_suf1.png" 20 > suf1.txt
```

you should do something like find/ls to get the file. My file looks like:

```
kent$  cat suf1.txt
apple_001_suf1.png
apple_002_suf1.png
apple_003_suf1.png
apple_004_suf1.png
apple_005_suf1.png
...
apple_020_suf1.png
```

**2) shuf, calculate 70% and generating mv commands:**

```
kent$  shuf suf1.txt|awk '{a[NR]=$0}END{l=NR*0.7;s="mv \"%s\" /path/dest\n"; for(x=1;x<=l;x++){printf s,a[x];sub("suf1","suf2",a[x]);printf s, a[x]}}'                      
mv "apple_008_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_008_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_011_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_011_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_009_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_009_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_015_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_015_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_003_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_003_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_013_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_013_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_017_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_017_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_019_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_019_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_006_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_006_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_016_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_016_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_010_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_010_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_004_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_004_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_018_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_018_suf2.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_005_suf1.png" /path/dest
mv "apple_005_suf2.png" /path/dest
```

you can see, 70% of 20 is 14, so there are 28 mv commands generated. and, as you required, randomly.

well you don't have to print them out, I just want to show you the commands here. you could just do :

```
shuf suf1.txt|awk '..my awk codes here..'|sh
```

to do the `mv` operation. of course, the `/path/dest` is just for example.

good luck.

Comment: i really appreciate the help, but right now i'm in a hurry and i need to do this quick and dirty. I'd really appreciate to have some code to temper with. Thank you.

Comment: @user996922 I thought of it. give me some minutes, I write an example for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

n70=$(( $(ls -1 *suffix1.png | wc -l) * 70 / 100 ))
for name in *suffix1.png
do
        echo $RANDOM "$name"
done | sort | sed "s=^[0-9][0-9]* ==;s=1\.png==" |\
  head -$n70 | xargs -n 1 -I % echo mv %{1,2}.png /path/to/dest/dir
```

- save it into dir where your image are
- replace /path/to/dest/dir with a real one (must exists)
- run and check the result (will do nothing, only show what will move - dry run)
- remove the "echo" from the xargs is satified for the real run
- warning: the filenames **should not** contain spaces...